# `ggplot2` axis.text margin with modified scale position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure if I've encountered a bug or am doing incorrectly. When specifying `axis.text` margins in ggplot, and moving the position of the axis, the settings to not persist.

Without moving the axis text, there is plenty of space around the axis:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "red", margin = margin(40, 40, 40, 40)))
```

[image: plot with extra margins]

But, when the position is changed, the margins do not apply:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(position = "right") + #This is the new line
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "red", margin = margin(40, 40, 40, 40)))
```

[image]

I'd expect the margins to carry over regardless of whether the axis.text is on the right or left. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe you have indeed found a bug. I'd post it as an issue on the ggplot2 repo.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this arises because the appearance of the right side y-axis label is dictated by `axis.text.y.right` in `theme()`, and while it inherits from `axis.text.y`, **it only inherits arguments that are not stated in `axis.text.y.right` itself**.

According to details in `?theme`, the chain of inheritance for `axis.text.y.right` goes as follows:

`axis.text.y.right` -> `axis.text.y` -> `axis.text` -> `text`

The default theme in ggplot is `theme_grey`. Enter `theme_grey` (without `()` at the end) into your console, and you'll see the full function. Let's look at the relevant bits:

```
function(base_size = 11, base_family = "", base_line_size = base_size/22, 
         base_rect_size = base_size/22) {

  half_line <- base_size/2

  theme(text = element_text(family = base_family, 
                            face = "plain", 
                            colour = "black",
                            size = base_size, 
                            lineheight = 0.9, 
                            hjust = 0.5, 
                            vjust = 0.5, 
                            angle = 0, 
                            margin = margin(), 
                            debug = FALSE), 

        axis.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8), 
                                 colour = "grey30"), 

        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 0.8 * half_line/2), 
                                   hjust = 1), 

        axis.text.y.right = element_text(margin = margin(l = 0.8 * half_line/2), 
                                         hjust = 0), 
        ...
        complete = TRUE)
}
```

`?element_text` shows the full list of arguments that `element_text` expects:

```
element_text(family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL,
  hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL,
  color = NULL, margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE)
```

Given all the inheritance, what are `axis.text.y.right`'s actual arguments in `theme_grey`?

- family = `base_family` (from `text`)
- face = `"plain"` (from `text`)
- colour = `"grey30"` (from `axis.text`, which overrides `text`'s `"black"`)
- size = 80% of `base_size` (from `axis.text`'s `rel(0.8)` modification of `text`'s `base_size`)
- hjust = `0` (from `axis.text.y.right`, which overrides `axis.text.y`'s `1`, which overrides `text`'s `0.5`)
- vjust = `0.5` (from `text`)
- angle = `0` (from `text`)
- lineheight = `0.9` (from `text`)
- margin = `margin(l = 0.8 * half_line/2)` (from `axis.text.y.right`, which overrides `axis.text.y`'s `margin = margin(r = 0.8 * half_line/2`, which overrides `text`'s `margin()`)
- debug = `FALSE` (from `text`)
- inherit.blank = `FALSE` (`element_text`'s default parameter)

As such, given a piece of code like below, `axis.text.y.right` will inherit `color = "red"` (which overrides `axis.text`'s `colour = "grey30"`). But since it has its own margin argument, it will not inherit `margin = margin(40, 40, 40, 40)`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "red", margin = margin(40, 40, 40, 40)))
```

Specifying `axis.text.y.right` instead of `axis.text.y` would do the trick:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  theme(axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red", margin = margin(40, 40, 40, 40)))
```